# Embedding SO Jobs home page on Facebook uses incorrect preview picture

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, facebook

When I embed the home page of SO careers on Facebook, it uses Stanford University's logo as a preview picture:

[image]

My only explanation is that Facebook's crawler goes check out the site, and is shown a Stanford job due to its geographical location. Because that's the first meaningful image on the page, the crawler goes on to assume that's a representative preview image for the site.

Bottom line, the site should serve a dedicated preview image [that Facebook can understand.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

Comment: Why ...? Why would anyone want to embed a page on Facebook. Don't we have enough problems already?

Comment: If you squint a little and imagine the tree bending to the right...

Comment: @rene heh. The example above is from mentioning SO careers in a Facebook conversation to someone looking for remote jobs though... probably a common enough use case to warrant fixing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow just updated its og:image tags at stackoverflow.com/jobs and related subpages, so that Facebook and Twitter now show a specified image when the page is shared.

Here's what happens now on Facebook:

[image]

And on Twitter:

[image]

Comment: Looking good, including in the context of a FB comment.

Answer (score 16):

Thank you for bringing this issue to our attention.  Although we don't see any logo at all when we try sharing on Facebook or when using their [sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing), we would like to see an appropriate logo, which looks easy to add.  So, we will do so at some point soon.

Comment: I'm always having to use the sharing debugger to 'Scrape Again' to refresh changes to og:image tags.  FB does have an API you can call to scrape and also a batch tool, hasn't been quite worth the effort yet to setup for me.